# How to add additional entity specific method in generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work, generic-collections

I have [followed this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and I learned about generic repository and unit of work.
But I am not clear with entity specific methods.
For example I have entities `Country` and `City`. 
By using generic repository I can use `Get()` or `GetById()` which will return me **country** or **city**:

```
 var countries = unitOfWork.CountryRepository.Get();
 var cities = unitOfWork.CityRepository.Get();
```

But Country have a `CountryCode` field and I want to get country by that field so I suppose that I have to add new method in generic repository class and call it like:

```
var countries = unitOfWork.CountryRepository.GetByCountryCode(string code);
```

but that means that I can also do this:

```
var countries = unitOfWork.CityRepository.GetByCountryCode(string code);
```

I am confused here and I know that I miss something.
How can I use generic repository and add additional entity specific methods?

**UPDATE**

I create repository class with additional method:

```
public class CountryRepository : GenericRepository<Country>
    {
        public CountryRepository(MainContext context) : base(context) { }

        public virtual Country GetByCode(string code)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(c => c.Code == code).First();
        }
    }
```

In UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private MainContext context = new MainContext();        
        private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
        private CountryRepository countryRepository;

        public GenericRepository<Country> CountryRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.countryRepository == null)
                {
                    this.countryRepository = new CountryRepository(context);
                }
                return countryRepository;
            }
        }
```

But from controller I don't see `GetByCode()`:

```
var country = unitOfWork.CountryRepository. // no GetByCode()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want methods specific to an entity then you declare those methods in that entity's repository specifically, i.e. your `GetByCountryCode` method is declared in the `CountryRepository` class, not the generic base class.

Comment: I have declared additional method in repository specific to entity but can't see new method in controllers. See my updated question please

Comment: Sorry I didn't changed return type from properties to `CountryRepository`. Tnx